# martingale representation of stock dynamics

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This may be a strange question, but I was curious about it. Under the discounted measure, one can write the lognormal price dynamics as:

$\frac{dS}{S} = \sigma dW$.

It is also Markov. Why is it that despite being Markov, it is somewhat industry-standard practice to use ***historical data*** to measure $\sigma$?

Comment: 1. "Since ... is martingale, it is also Markov". No. The martingale property is about *conditionals means*, which is much less than *conditional laws*. Anyway, this $S$ *is* Markov (though for different reasons). 2. The word "despite" is out of place. There is nothing strange in this practice. Say, the classical statistics is about measuring quantities like variance (which is similar to $\sigma$) from independent observations, which are even "worse" than Markov. But there is nothing wrong with this, and the independence even helps, while too much dependence leads to larger statistical errors.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear, thanks. But, even in the case where it is a martingale, so that $S(0) = \mathbb{E}[S(T) | \mathcal{F}(0)]$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a filtration, to use historical data to measure $\sigma$ is a bit strange, because, the historical data for stocks is in the form of a time series (usually), you don't have independent observations in $\sigma$.

Comment: To infer something about a parameter, such as $\sigma$, based on observations $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ you need to be able to specify a joint probability distribution of the observations conditional on the parameters $p(S_1,\ldots,S_n | \sigma)$, if they are independent this is easy, you get $\prod_i p(S_i | \sigma)$, but in the Markov case you get something only slightly more complicated $\prod_i p(S_i | S_{i-1}, \sigma)$

Answer (score 0):

First of all , the discounted stock price is a martingale, not the stock itself. $$dD(t)S(t)=\sigma D(t)S(t)dW(t)$$, under the risk neutral measure(what you called "discounted measure"), and $D$ the discounting process.

This measure is tied to a world where you are risk-averse . In other words, I can have a position, and remove the risk by taking another position. Therefore, the market tells you where $\sigma$ is, not its past or future. This world guarantees non-arbitrage prices. It makes no sense to use this measure and value $\sigma$ by using an historical estimate, a simple look at any time series will tell you that $S_t$ is not a martingale...